# Undefined index: start_time in CRM Volunteer BAO NeedSearch.php

Tags: civivolunteer

Drupal 7.67
Civicrm 5.15.2
CiviVolunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1

I have the following error message on Volunteer Event registration "Volunteer Now" screen:

Notice: Undefined index: start_time in CRM_Volunteer_BAO_NeedSearch::usortDateAscending() (line 299 of /home/mysite/public_html/members/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/BAO/NeedSearch.php).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to apply this PR https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/513. I this it should fix the notice error.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: I made the changes and now get this error message:
Notice: Undefined index: project_contacts in CRM_Volunteer_BAO_NeedSearch->search() (line 126 of /home/public_html/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/BAO/NeedSearch.php).

The file ang/volunteer/VolOppsCtrl.html had the changes already in it.

I also notice when editing error "X"  on lines 45, 174 and 176

44              class="big crm-form-text">
45              <option />

174                ng-click="toggleSelection(need)"
175            </span>
176          </td>

Comment: Above error message is on event link screen.

Also error message on Events template screen
" Notice: Undefined index: start_date in CRM_Volunteer_BAO_Project->getEntityAttributes() (line 670 of /home/willycg/public_html/members/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/BAO/Project.php).